# I have set up a centos7 server for my application and cannot connect it to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, centos7

I have moved my application from a Xampp server to a Centos7 server. I have an s3 bucket on AWS which contains the code for the front end of my application and to deploy my code to that bucket I have to run the following command in the terminal:

```
aws s3 sync build/ s3://application_name --profile=profile_name -- acl public-read -- exclude 'node_modules/*|.env
```

The error I got was that the profile was not recognised so I then the following command:

```
aws configure –profile=”profile_name”
```

Then I provided the following details which I will not give all the answers too:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 
AWS_REGION = eu-west-1
Output = json
```

I then got the following error

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I am now unsure what to do. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, it seems that you don't have s3:ListBucket permission associated with the access credentials you are using.

You also need to check the bucket policy to see if there is an explicit deny present over there for other users and if you are falling into that category. Generally, to secure the bucket security team allow only a few users to access the bucket.

Comment: The bucket is publicly accessible

Comment: Does the IAM user has permission to s3:ListBucket and s3:PutObject?